# What is a method to learn to automate web browser functions?

Tags: browser, automation

I am trying to learn how to create a program that will automate web browser functions like filling out forms as well as clicking buttons. The program must be able to run multiple tasks at one time.

For example: fill out a form on 2 pages at the same time. I did some research and found that I would have to most likely use a C language and ASP.NET. Speed is definitely a factor as well.  The program must be able to automate the functions extremely quickly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your best option is probably javascript. Disclaimer: spoken with only cursory experience in the language.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this with Selenium. Selenium supports several browsers & many languages. http://docs.seleniumhq.org/about/platforms.jsp#programming-languages

Your other option would be to send cURL requests to the address the forms are sending the data to.

It depends on the forms as to which method above is simpler.